# UA Dimensions & Metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, metrics, dimensions

I am using the GA4 (Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4) reporting API to create a dashboard for my company.
I noticed that if you select the following dimension:-

```
TIME/ga:dateHourMinute,
ADWORDS/ga:adwordsCampaignID
ADWORDS/ga:adwordsAdGroupID
```

with METRICS:-

```
ga:impressions, 
ga:CPC 
ga:adCost no data is returned
```

BUT if you change the selection to dimensions:-

```
TIME/ga:date, 
ADWORDS/ga:adwordsCampaignID, 
ADWORDS/ga:adwordsAdGroupID
```

with METRICS:-

```
ga:impressions, 
ga:CPC
ga:adCost
```

data is returned. Does anyone know how to get the first query to return data?

Answer (score 1):

The dimension `ga:dateHourMinute` is not compatible with the metrics `ga:impressions`, `ga:CPC`, and `ga:adCost`. Google Analytics does not store these metrics broken down by date, hour, and minute. If you send the first query, you will get that the dimensions and metrics are incompatible:

[image: incompatible response]

You can visit the [dimension & metric explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) to plan a query for compatible dimensions and metrics. If you check the fields `ga:adwordsCampaignID`, `ga:adwordsAdGroupID`, `ga:impressions`, `ga:CPC`, and `ga:adCost`, then the dimension `ga:dateHourMinute` is grayed out to signify incompatibility:

[image: ga:dateHourMinutes is incompatible]

Comment: Would their be any chance in the future that this would be possible? Is there another api that I can use to get the datetime for ga:adwordsCampaignID, ga:adwordsAdGroupID, impressions and or ga:keyword for measure ga:CPC

Comment: Campaigns in the Google Ads API support "hour" as a segment: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v8/campaign. However, minute is not available.